# Adding runat server to HTML control giving error

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to access a`HTML control` on server side, but while adding `runat= server`, it is giving me error as

> 'chkA1<%# (Container.RecordIndex) %>' is not a valid identifier.

Here is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkA1<%# (Container.RecordIndex)%>" name="chkAC1" style="width: 17px; 
                                                height: 17px;" value="<%# (Container.RecordIndex)%>" onclick="AppoveCheckA(this)" />
```

When I remove `runat=server` it works properly.

Why it is not working with `runat=server`. Any suggestion

**UPDATE**

The Id's are  changing accordingly of the checkboxes. Here is the code which I have written

```
var checkBoxID;
    var status;
    var arrA = [];
    var arrB = [];
    var rowIndex
    function AppoveCheckA(chk) {
        status = true;
        checkBoxID = $(chk).attr("id");
        funClientSelectAfter(status, checkBoxID);
    }
    function AppoveCheckB(chk) {
        status = true;
        checkBoxID = $(chk).attr("id");
        funClientSelectAfter1(status, checkBoxID);
    }

    function funClientSelectAfter(status, checkBoxID) {
        if (status && checkBoxID != null) {
            var len = checkBoxID.length;

            if (len >= 7) {
                rowIndex = checkBoxID.substring(checkBoxID.length - 2, checkBoxID.length);
            }
            else {
                rowIndex = checkBoxID.substring(checkBoxID.length - 1, checkBoxID.length);

            }
            for (var col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
                if (("chkA" + col + rowIndex) == checkBoxID) {
                    if (document.getElementById("chkA" + col + rowIndex).checked == true) {
                        $("#chkA" + col + rowIndex).attr("checked", true);
                        arrA[rowIndex] = col;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        arrA[rowIndex] = 0
                }
                $("#chkA" + col + rowIndex).attr("checked", false);
            }
            document.getElementById("hidRateA").value = arrA.join();
            // alert(document.getElementById("hidRateA").value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is going to be a strongly typed identifier in C#. Therefore the ID can't change and it can't contain invalid characters.

The simple solution is to just remove that from your id attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkA1" name="chkAC1" style="width: 17px; height: 17px;" value="<%# (Container.RecordIndex)%>" onclick="AppoveCheckA(this)" />
```

Comment: the `id's` are changing but, there are many rows in the gridview and id changes accordingly

Comment: @coder Add the code accessing this input into your question.

Comment: @coder What about the server side code? And on the client side, you don't have to access it by ID. You can use CSS classes are even the value of other attributes (such as value).